# JTabbedPane Selected Component always null

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage, jtabbedpane

```
getTabbedPane().addTab("Ground", pnlGround);

public BufferedImage getSelectedImage() { 
    return ((SpritePane) getTabbedPane().getSelectedComponent()).getSelectedImage();
}
```

`getTabbedPane().getSelectedComponent()` is returning null. It is called directly after I select a JPanel I have next to the JTabbedPane, that is the only reason I can come up with why the method would be returning a null component; because the tab is open but doesn't have focus.

Yet I am to find a way to get the opened tab in the JTabbedPane.

Also, `getTabbedPane().getComponentAt(i)` always returns null. There are 6 tabs.

getSelectedIndex() is returning the correct index, yet it still says the component is null if I pass that in.

P.S. SpritePane is just a subclass of JPanel.

Comment: Please show an SSCCE that illustrates the problem, most likely something is wrong elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the active/selected tab try

```
int idx = getTabbedPane().getSelectedIndex();
```

You can then get the component of the tab (e.g. a panel) with

```
Componennt c = getTabbedPane().getComponent(idx);
```

Comment: Didn't see Gilberto's comment. +1

Comment: getSelectedIndex returns null?

Comment: getSelectedIndex() is returning the correct index, yet it still says the component is null if I pass that index into getTabbedPane().getComponentAt(i)

Comment: I think you need to post more code. I don't see how you can have a tab without calling `addTab(String title, Component comp)`.

Comment: -1 != getSelectedIndex()  implies null != getSelectedComponent() - no additional magic and no reason to go a detour ... something else is wrong